# Sudden datastore exceptions : DatastoreFailureException: Missing or invalid authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google Appengine app (Java) and the datastore was recently auto-migrated into "Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode" (completed on 6/6/2022) that has been running for years.

It has now started throwing these exceptions in new deployments without any relevant code change to trigger them:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreFailureException: Missing or invalid authentication.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseQueryResultsSource.getIndexList(BaseQueryResultsSource.java:154)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseQueryResultsSource.loadMoreEntities(BaseQueryResultsSource.java:187)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseQueryResultsSource.loadMoreEntities(BaseQueryResultsSource.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureLoaded(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:146)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.hasNext(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:64)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeysOnlyIterator.hasNext(KeysOnlyIterator.java:29)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ChunkIterator.next(ChunkIterator.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ChunkIterator.next(ChunkIterator.java:20)
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:52)
    at com.google.common.collect.MultitransformedIterator.hasNext(MultitransformedIterator.java:50)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$PeekingImpl.hasNext(Iterators.java:1105)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ChunkingIterator.hasNext(ChunkingIterator.java:51)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:366)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:163)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.MakeListResult.translate(MakeListResult.java:22)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.MakeListResult.translate(MakeListResult.java:12)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy.invoke(ResultProxy.java:34)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.isEmpty(Unknown Source)
```

My code. After loading a list of entities, the exception is thrown on the isEmpty() call on the returned list:

```
List<SystemSetting> applicationSettings = ofy().load().type(SystemSetting.class).filter("name", name).list(); 

if (applicationSettings.isEmpty()) { // Exception thrown here
```

It's worth also noting that on previous versions, datastore reads and writes are still happening without any issues. It is only new deployments that exhibit this issue. However, redeploying previous versions from previous commits using the same CI service to deploy them are failing.

Is this caused by the datastore migration?

Slight update: these errors are only happening on newly deployed versions... In fact, I deployed a new version (from CI, bitbucket pipeline) that worked, but when I redeployed it with no changes it no longer works. Same app engine version id, code and users etc.

Things we've tried without success:

1. Re-deploying last known version
2. Clearing memcache
3. Deploying from local dev
4. Stopping instances
5. Trying alternative service account key
6. Expanding service account permissions
7. Clearing BitBucket pipeline caches (the CI builder)
8. Have recreated the issue with datastore api directly (no objectify)
9. Have redeployed with different user account - no success
10. Have redeployed with new service account - no success

**Update 1:**

If I [run the following code on a local java application](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java) (pointing at live datastore using same service account) it works locally, but fails if I deploy to app engine with my project-id.

```
DatastoreOptions datastoreOptions = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance();
Datastore datastore = datastoreOptions.getService();

// A known entity in my live datastore
Key key = datastore.newKeyFactory()
                   .setKind("MyEntityType")
                   .newKey(123123123l);
Entity retrieved = datastore.get(key);
```

When it fails, I can get slightly more information:

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected Error code 500 trying to get security access token from Compute Engine metadata for the default service account: Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
```

full stack:

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: I/O error
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:123)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.lookup(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$3.call(DatastoreImpl.java:434)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$3.call(DatastoreImpl.java:431)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl.lookup(DatastoreImpl.java:430)
...
Caused by: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: I/O error, code=UNAVAILABLE
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:171)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:117)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.lookup(Datastore.java:93)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.lookup(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:171)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected Error code 500 trying to get security access token from Compute Engine metadata for the default service account: Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:206)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:257)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$1.call(OAuth2Credentials.java:254)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials$AsyncRefreshResult.executeIfNew(OAuth2Credentials.java:580)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.asyncFetch(OAuth2Credentials.java:220)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:170)
    at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.http.CensusHttpModule$CensusHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(CensusHttpModule.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc$1.initialize(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:91)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:95)
    ... 76 more
```

**Update 2:**

I've since paid for Google support and they have now confirmed it "is linked to a known issue related to the GAE standard Service Agent and access token which is affecting some users"

Comment: What is the code that produces that error?

Comment: After loading a list of entites, the exception is thrown on the `isEmpty()` call on the returned list:    
```
List<SystemSetting> applicationSettings = ofy().load().type(SystemSetting.class).filter("name", name).list();

if (applicationSettings.isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: @AlexMamo, I just added a slight update to mention that I've realised it's only newly deployed versions that have this problem (I didn't realise that initially from the logs)

Comment: As you mentioned in the stackoverflow question that datastore was recently auto-migrated into "Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode"- this will happen if you disabled or deleted your App Engine default service account, your App Engine app will lose access to your Datastore mode database. If you disabled your App Engine service account, you can re-enable it, see enabling a service account. If you deleted your App Engine service account within the last 30 days, you can restore your service account, see undeleting a service account.

Comment: Adding PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com with the role Editor should fix the issue. Now the new version can be deployed to the old projects.

Also you must know with the usage of Client Libraries, it makes use of the Application Default Credentials. If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, ADC uses the default service account that App Engine provides for applications running over that service, you should not define the environment variable, so that App Engine uses its default Service Account.

Comment: Reference : https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#datastore-permissions-for-app-engine

Comment: Thanks @PriyashreeBhadra, those are good suggestions but don't apply to me. I've since paid for Google support and they have now confirmed it "is linked to a known issue related to the GAE standard Service Agent and access token which is affecting some users"

Comment: Oh great!. Yes I checked your issue is indeed linked to a known issue and there is an ongoing investigation for the same. Please follow the Google Support case for further updates.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra, yeah, it was fixed last night and now new deployments are working again.

Comment: I had the same issue and it's now fixed for me too. Do we have a reference to that isue?

Comment: @lordofmax, I found nothing public, just the private chats I was having with Google support team